# Ion-refresh not entering function

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I'm working on an Ionic 1 project, wherein I am calling an API to retrieve data. But the ion-refresh doesn't seem to be working as expected. It doesn't enter the function it is supposed to on refreshing. Here's my code:

HTML code:

```
<ion-view view-title="Hotels" ng-controller="AgHotelCtrl">
  <ion-content>
<ion-refresher pulling-text="Pull to refresh..." on-refresh="init()">
</ion-refresher>
<ul class="list">
    <li ng-repeat="r in res" class="item">
      <h2>{{r.name}}</h2>
      <p>{{r.locality}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
 </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

JS Code:

```
.controller('AgHotelCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
 var init = function() {
console.log("hola");
var user = $state.params.user;
$scope.res=[];
var whereClause = "agent_email = '" + user.email + "'";
var queryBuilder = Backendless.DataQueryBuilder.create().setWhereClause( whereClause );
Backendless.Data.of("Hotels").find( queryBuilder )
  .then(function(foundHotels) {
    $scope.res = foundHotels;
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("error" + error.message);
  })
 }
 init();
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `on-refresh="init()"` looks for `$scope.init()` method. However you have local `init` not binded to `$scope`

*Fix:*

I would change `init` to `doRefresh`:

```
<ion-refresher pulling-text="Pull to refresh..." on-refresh="doRefresh()">
```

And in controller add:

```
$scope.doRefresh = function(){
 init();
}
```

Comment: Worked fine. Thank you, Although, the data doesn't immediately load when switching views. I always have to refresh the page in order to load the list.